# WCF Service Security Exception caused when trying to access data via LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, wcf, security, service

I'm currently in the beginning of learning WCF, as some of the concepts and the functionality they provide look interesting and also useful in a project I'm undertaking.

So far I've been following some pretty simple guides to get the hang of it but after creating my first host service I've come a bit unstuck, after trying to retrieve some data from a SQL Database and recieving the following error while using LINQ to SQL:

```
Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

I've had a look around and seen some suggestions as how to fix this, but non have seemed to be applicable as I'm creating a simple WCF service library purely for testing.

The code trips up on the following line:

```
me = aDb.Messages.ToList();
```

The project itself is held on a remote drive, but when I run to debug is run locally, however the database is a test server located again remotely. All the SQL credentials are correct as the connection tests succesfully and I've checked the connection string. Finally the service is running as a basicHttp Below you can see all my code so if you have any ideas as to how I can stop the error it would be appreciated.

```
namespace AnnouncementServiceLibrary
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IConnect
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<Mess> ConnectUser(string userId);
    }
}

namespace AnnouncementServiceLibrary
{
    public class AnnounceService : IAnnounceService
    {
#region IConnect Members

        public List<Mess> ConnectUser(string userId)
        {
                List<Mess> mess = new List<Mess>();
                List<Message> me;
                List<MessageLink> messLink;

                AnnouncementDBDataContext aDb = new AnnouncementDBDataContext();

                me = aDb.Messages.ToList();
                messLink = aDb.MessageLinks.ToList();

                var result = (from a in messLink
                              join b in me
                                  on a.UniqueID equals b.UniqueID
                              where a.UserID == userId
                              select new { b.UniqueID, b.Author, b.Title, b.Body, b.Priority, a.Read, b.TimeRecieved }).
                    DefaultIfEmpty();

                foreach (var a in result)
                {
                    mess.Add(new Mess(a.UniqueID, a.Author, a.Title, a.Body, a.Priority, (bool)a.Read, a.TimeRecieved));
                }
                return mess;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could all be tied back to the fact that your application is building from a network share. Take a look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2003/06/20/57023.aspx

Comment: Thanks didn't see that one, have some rep on me.